# Check if elements with same attribute have any child elements that has classname active

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to find if all (ul) elements have the matching data-validation of (required) AND any of its children (li) have the class of (active). I just want to make sure the (required) ul have active divs.

My code is of the following:

```
<div class="fields">
    <ul class="ul-cls" data-validation="required">
        <li><div class="active"></div></liv>
        <li><div class=" "></div></liv>
    </ul>

    <ul class="ul-cls" data-validation="required">
        <li><div class="active"></div></liv>
        <li><div class=" "></div></liv>
        <li><div class=" "></div></liv>
        <li><div class="active"></div></liv>
    </ul>

    <ul class="ul-cls" data-validation="not-required">
        <li><div class="active"></div></liv>
        <li><div class="active"></div></liv>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My JavaScript code is:

```
$(".fields .ul-cls").each(function() {
    if ($(".ul-cls", this).attr('data-validation') == 'required') {
        if ($("li div.active").length >=1) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.every` to check that every `.fields .ul-cls[data-validation="required"]` has an `.active` descendant. Also note that you should end `<li>` tags with `</li>`, not `</liv>`:

```js
const allActive = Array.prototype.every.call(
  $('.fields .ul-cls[data-validation="required"]'),
  ul => $(ul).find('.active').length >= 1
);
if (allActive) {
  console.log('all are active!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fields">
  <ul class="ul-cls" data-validation="required">
    <li>
      <div class="active"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class=" "></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="ul-cls" data-validation="required">
    <li>
      <div class="active"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class=" "></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class=" "></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="active"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="ul-cls" data-validation="not-required">
    <li>
      <div class="active"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="active"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Non-passing example:

```js
const allActive = Array.prototype.every.call(
  $('.fields .ul-cls[data-validation="required"]'),
  ul => $(ul).find('.active').length >= 1
);
if (allActive) {
  console.log('all are active!');
} else {
  console.log('fail');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fields">
  <ul class="ul-cls" data-validation="required">
    <li>
      <div>this one is required but not active</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class=" "></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="ul-cls" data-validation="required">
    <li>
      <div class="active"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class=" "></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class=" "></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="active"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="ul-cls" data-validation="not-required">
    <li>
      <div class="active"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="active"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @CertainPerformance - However, doesn't work :(
Only 3 actives should validate and not all 7

Comment: What do you mean, "only 3 actives should validate"? What 7 are you referring to? There are only 5 `.active`s in your HTML. Were you expecting a different output for this HTML?

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to only validate if any <div> has class of "active" where it's parent is (.ul-cls[data-validation="required"])... which in the example would be 3.. Kinda like in a form validation where there are fields that required and some that are not. I was wanting to make sure Just the element(s) that are required have divs with any active classes

Comment: By `if any <div> has class of "active" where it's parent is` do you actually mean *every*, not *any*? You want to make sure that every `.active` element is a child of a `required`?

Comment: No. Any, because it would work as a radio or checkbox

Comment: It's still not clear what you're looking for - per your question title, the code in the answer will check whether all elements with `required` have at least one `.active` child. Or, as your above comment implies, do you want to look the other way around, from a `.active` to a parent `required`? Please explain specifically what you're looking for

Comment: Sorry, thank you for your patience with me. I have updated the title to reflect m question

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` to get the desired element / class inside your `ul-cls` class with `this`, like below. I edited your HTML content in the snippet and added `active` class on the first `ul div` to check the condition.

```js
$(".fields .ul-cls").each(function() {

  if ($(this).attr('data-validation') == 'required') {
      if ($(this).find($("li div.active")).length == $(this).find($(" li div")).length) {
      console.log('Pass the test')
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fields">
  <ul class="ul-cls" data-validation="required">
    <li>
      <div class="active"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="active"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="ul-cls" data-validation="required">
    <li>
      <div class="active"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class=" "></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class=" "></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="active"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="ul-cls" data-validation="not-required">
    <li>
      <div class="active"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="active"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance , @Shree - Could I get the `length` of how many elements have Required and get the `length` of how many active classes within the elements required and `if (numActive >= numReq) // do something`

Comment: why not just loop inside required and get active number ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work!

```
 SetTimeout(function(){

 var numReq = $('.fields .ul-cls[data-validation="required"]').length,
     numSel = $('.fields .ul-cls[data-validation="required"] li div.active').length; 

 console.log(numReq+"->"+numSel);

 if(numSel >= numReq){
     alert('validated!')
 }else{
    console.log('not valid')
 }
}, 100); 

// Set Timeout because click action delays update
```